# How to getMethods into a class while Reading a File using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, file, class, methods

I have two classes, one with instance variables and the other will read a file. The file with one main loop will store an array of workers. I don't know when the getMethods should be placed.

the file has looks a bit like this:

```
Joames peter 5 15.00
Laura Kelly 30 12.00
Tim McAdam 18 15.00
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class PayRoll {
    private static Scanner kbd;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 15;

        final String INPUT_FILE = "data.txt";
        Worker[] worker_ar = new Worker[NUMBER_OF_WORKERS];

        try{
            kbd = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("File Not Found!");
        }

        String line = null;
        int i = 0 ;
        while((kbd.hasNextLine()) && (i < worker_ar.length))
        {
            // these are the variables I have in the other class. I need these so I can 
            // later reverse the file data and comute total pay and average pay. 
            line = kbd.nextLine(); 
            worker_ar[i] = (getfName(), getlName(), getHours(), gethrly_pay());
            i++;
        }

        kbd.close();
    }
    // I will put two  methods here to make the file reverse
}
```

Comment: Try a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the data of the workers from the INPUT_FILE?

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer with space separator.

Nitpick: Use Employee instead of Worker. It's has more sense, and Worker used in Java for something else.